# Просмотр видео в eBook Maestro Pro

Tags: ebook, видео, html

как создать книгу с помощью программы eBook Maestro Pro, чтобы на ее страницах можно было просматривать видео? То есть я создаю html страницу, прикрепляю на нее видео, затем преобразую все файлы в книгу и уже в книге на этих страницах видео не отображается. Может дело в браузере, с помощью которого открывается видео в книге. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: а может быть и нет...

Answer (score 1):

Вот не плохой и современный. На странице сайта под демо самого плеера есть кнопочка - Получить Код. Скопируйте и разберитесь с настройками...
http://www.videojs.com/

Use Video.js
In the :

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.11/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.11/video.js"></script>
In the <body>:

<video id="MY_VIDEO_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
 preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg"
 data-setup="{}">
 <source src="MY_VIDEO.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
 <source src="MY_VIDEO.webm" type='video/webm'>
 <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
</video>
```

Довольно не плохо и просто.

Или с помощью iframe.

```
<iframe width="854" height="510" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/BEaR64qlSTg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

где src="...." надо заменить на ваши... может я что-то упустил...